Properties of coils used in a power transmitter and receiver
I am completely new to wireless power transfer. I need to model a wireless power transfer link with the help of a Bode 100.
This is the reference document given to me.
Before starting this, I would like to know the ideal properties of coils used in wireless power transmitter and receiver.

What are the things to be considered when selecting coil for wireless power transfer?
When can I say the coil selected is a good one?

Page 4 of the reference shows the following image. How did they arrive at 125kHz? I can see from the graph that before and after 125KHz the inductance is only 23.45uH.



what are ideal properties of coils used in wireless power transmitter
and receiver.

The only common ideal properties that wireless power coils have are

low loss i.e. low series resistance loss
high current handling capacity (transmitter)
an open magnetic structure


What are the things to be considered when selecting coil for wireless
power transfer

It depends entirely on the application you are considering. Bigger diameter coils "throw" magnetic flux further and, you can get decent/sufficient wireless power transfer at larger ranges. But, if you are just trying to illuminate a Christmas tree LED at several inches you won't want a receive coil that is very big compared to the transmit coil. Neither will you want the same number of turns. Different applications require different solutions.

When can I say the coil selected is a good one

Don't put the cart before the horses; you select a good one based on the application.

How did they arrive at 125kHz?

It's a standard frequency used so, there are chipset designs that are available. I tend to make my own drivers and therefore I'm not limited in the frequency I choose.
The Bode 100 document you linked is not really useful to you I would say. It's missing the point and is probably more of a document that is aimed at making sales rather than helping you figure things out.
What you should do is simulate something that is appropriate for your application. That application is dictated by power availability and how good your transmitter coil winding needs to be.

Thank you Andy. "The Bode 100 document you linked is not really useful to you I would say. It's missing the point" .May I know what it is missing. And also what you mean by "an open magnetic structure"

The document doesn't justify why they chose those coils or what the application is as far as I can tell. Everything you need to design is application led. An example of an closed magnetic structure is like a shielded coil or partially shielded coil. A bobbin coil (used as a small energy receiver) can be regarded as having an open magnetic structure. Open coils placed close to metal conductive parts can be regarded as having a degraded open magnetic structure.

Can I consider Litz wire as a closed magnetic structure?

@Confused no, litz wire brings lower losses to the party and nothing else. It's the shape of the coil (litz or plain copper) and what other conductive things in the vicinity that dictate how far the field can usefully extend (more open).

I measured the inductance of the coil.The value I got is 4.59uH. Can I say in general like higher the inductance coil is better or lower the inductance coil is better. Anything like that.

For a transmitter coil, lower inductance is usually the best route because, it's current that needs to flow to generate an external magnetic field and, if you have a higher inductance you'll need hundreds of volts to get the current needed (compared to tens of volts with much lower inductance). This is a generalism of course @Confused

Thank you.This information is very helpful .Can I consider the opposite for RX coil.

@Confused you usually want more turns on the RX coil in order to create sufficient dc voltage after rectification. Too little DC voltage is a situation that can't be easily remedied.
